# WPF Numeric Textbox control with a calculator?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, controls

I've always liked the ability to do simple calculations in the same place I'm entering a number when working in MS Money.

[image]

I know that [DevExpress](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theprogressbar/archive/2010/08/11/new-editor-controls-for-wpf-and-silverlight-coming-in-v2010-vol-2.aspx) is working on one, but don't want to buy the full WPF bloat only for this control.

Do you know a control like that for WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [CalculatorUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CalculatorUpDown) control from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) project.

[image: CalculatorUpDown Control]